# Nginx 403 Forbidden error on a simple conf file

Tags: server, nginx

I've got a new Ubuntu 18.04 droplet on DO, by following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) guide.
Just installed Nginx and Ufw (which is disabled for now) on it.
I've this conf file inside the /etc/nginx/conf.d folder.

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;

        root /var/www/2;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 2.hotelbobbygg.xyz;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

In the error log, this is written `*7 directory index of "/var/www/2/" is forbidden, client: 139.5.37.198, server: 2.hotelbobbygg.xyz, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "2.hotelbobbygg.xyz"`

I've also tried commenting out the 3rd line from last, i.e. `try_files` line. But it still behaves the same. Pls help what is preventing me to access the index.html lying inside /var/www/2 folder.

And if I used below given text in that ../conf.d/2.conf file (replacing what is already there), then also it doesn't succeed (rather falls back on serving the /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html).

```
server {
        listen 80; listen [::]:80;
        server_name 2.hotelbobbygg.xyz;  # <-- change this

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                root /var/www;
        }

        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Comment: Try and check permissions and ownership of the directory in question.

Comment: I've followed and did these things as told in many many other answers google led me to. But its not solved. And I've done so many permissions things but its still the same. Sometimes I tinker too much, then nginx stops reloading/testing and gives error.

Comment: Sorry for my vagueness in my last comment. What I wanted to say that I tried giving execution permissions to www-data user to all folders in the path, as told in many other help articles.

Comment: It makes sense, you need execute permissions in order to `cd` into a directory.

Comment: Yes. But it didn't work. Still giving the same error.

Comment: Can you add `ls -lh` on that directory and also paste the output of `whoami`?

Comment: I was running all commands as root and my /etc/nginx/conf.d had only a conf file related to this installation (and /sites-enabled/default file was deleted). And /var/www too only had 1 index.html file (all had been given Executiion permissions as told in various articles).
But since then, I've created a new DO droplet and all is working find on that as of now.
So, pls tell me how can I close this question reasonably now?

Comment: You can either try and answer your own question or remove your question completely (not recommended because there's some knowledge here).

Comment: Check the user in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (user www-data). Then check the permissions for that owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I moved ahead and reinstalled the ubuntu on the droplet, this problem is no longer bothering me. So, pls consider this closed.

But for anybody who visits this thread again, I would like to add that I tried changing permissions (i.e. gave execution permissions) etc on all the paths, which is told in the different (first 10) results which google throws at you.

Sorry that I can't be more specific, since some days have passed in between. But I would repeat again that I did all the permissions changes as was expected of me on different folders/paths in the way of index.html files etc.

Comment: The issue was you didn't define an index file with the `index` command so it tries the URI as entered and then tries to list the directories which 403s because you don't have `autoindex` enabled for the config block.

Comment: But in my code pasted here above, the 5th line of command WAS 'index' command only. Although I do think you're giving a new type of solution, which no other google help article provided.

Comment: the only other issue would he a permissions issue because that's what 403 means.  But as you solved this already theres really nothing more we can do here...

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. I proved to be a bit impatient.

Comment: Yes, I think Thomas is correct. `autoindex` is disabled by default and that's what fixed it for me.